# (Follow up) Can a thicker model giver a lower critical buckling load?

Tags: finite-element-method, buckling

I present three seperate models with thickness of t = 0.005m, 0.01m and 0.025m respectively, all have a forced displacement of -0.01m in the x-direction, and fixed on the other end. As you can see the critical load factor (number by which you have to multiply your loads to reach buckling) increases alongside the thickness.

[image]

[image]
[image]

But then suddenly at thickness t=0.035m the buckling mode drops all the way to 0.04095. Could this be right or is there most likely something else going on?

[image]

Comment: I would double check that you haven't used t=0.0035m instead of t=0.035m

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a thicker model have a lower critical buckling load?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44838/can-a-thicker-model-have-a-lower-critical-buckling-load)

Comment: You can trace the problem by applying the anticipated buckling loads (CLF*F) back to those models, and check the respective stress and displacement at locations currently shown. For all models, the stresses and displacements shall be identical as they all subjected to the buckling load in proportion to their thickness. Otherwise, either the program contains bugs or the way it reports the configuration is infinite rigid (L too short is one of the possibilities).

Comment: If the last plot is "fixed on one end," why are all the "surface displacement magnitudes" approximately the same, i.e. something similar to a rigid body translation? Either you have an a modelling problem when you made the structure thicker, an input error, or a program bug (and I would guess one of the first two, not the bug).

Comment: @alephzero, I am not sure I follow, they are all fixed, all have the same inputs, the only thing I changed was the thickness. I copied and changed the thickness of the model, no other change.

Comment: Just look at the plot. What displacement does "dark blue" correspond to? When you say "I copied and changed the thickness of the model, no other change" you mean "I only INTENDED to change the thickness of the model". The output says you changed something else as well.

Comment: I changed Dimensions of the Krylov space from 0 to 300 in the last model (t = 0.035 m), because otherwise I did not get a buckling mode at all.

Comment: I plotted the stress strain curve of each buckling mode, and compared it with nonlinear buckling analysis data: https://imgur.com/a/MXAbyDj, as you can see the slope or Youngs Modulus seem to match well for all three plots, but the nonlinear model for t=0.035 seems to buckle at a much earlier point than the other two. What do you guys think?

Comment: "I changed Dimensions of the Krylov space from 0 to 300 in the last model". So the models are not identical. I don't know what is the "Krylov Space", and what effect the change from 0 (?) to 300 (?) has. If it increases the overall size/length, then the buckling characteristic may have changed. I wonder why you insist to force the 0.035 models to buckle by tinker its dimension, then question the result.

Comment: I am trying to check the effect increasing the thickness has on the critical buckling load.

Comment: For those wondering there was no problem with the model or COMSOL itself, I ran it on my own computer and got the expected results. Seems there are some issues with the cluster I tried to run it on.